# Loading jQuery with NodeJS

Tags: jquery, node.js

I have a working HTML file with some javascript in it. I use NodeJS to send it to the client using `fs.readFile()` and `response.write()`. The problem with this is that, although the HTML  renders fine, the javascript (which includes jQuery) doesn't load.

Comment: Don't say "loading jQuery with NodeJS". NodeJS shouldn't load it, the browser should.

Comment: uh, are you ending your response? `response.end()`.  Try using a framework. I like connect, but express is easier. These have static file handlers.

Comment: Code... post your source code where you are doing this magic.

Comment: Probably because you only have one case for the fsreadFile(), mainly for your html. You must also tell it that when you request something called jquery.js (or w/e), to read that specific file and send it back. But better to using something like express framework!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really shouldn't manually do "fs.readFile()" and "response.write()". Have a look at "lightnode" for serving static files: https://github.com/ngspinners/lightnode